# Passing address field to lists/subscribe using the MailChimp API 2.0 isn't working

Tags: api, mailchimp

I'm using the following code to add an email address to a list in MailChimp. All fields are sending through correctly except ADDRESS, which is just empty when I look in MailChimp.

I'm using the format described [here](http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/2.0/lists/subscribe.php#listssubscribeformat-_-v20) which tells me that I can pass a string with each piece of the address separated by two spaces.

```
$this->mc = new Mailchimp('{api key here}');
$address = array(
    'Line 1',
    'Line 2',
    'Line 3'
);
$this->mc->lists->subscribe('{list ID here}', array('email' => '{email here}'),array(
    'MMERGE6' => $title,
    'FNAME' => $first_name,
    'LNAME' => $surname,
    'ADDRESS' => implode('  ',$address),
    'TOWN' => $town,
    'POSTCODE' => $postcode,
    'COUNTRY' => $country,
    'MMERGE7' => $organisation,
    'MMERGE8' => $role,
    'MMERGE10' => $source, 
    'MMERGE11' => (!empty($newsletter) ? 'Yes' : 'No')
));
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: silly question, but just to make sure, have you double-checked that your address field's merge tag is "ADDRESS"?

Comment: Yeah it is. I ended up using the array syntax instead. Had problems with that until I learned that some of the fields are required and some aren't. Frustrating that it will silently fail.

Comment: @tprsn Where did you learn about which fields are required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned in your comment that you've switched to the array syntax, so this may not be helpful to you, but in case anyone else cares.

---

I was able to replicate the issue - passing "Line 1 Line 2 Line 3" (two spaces between each value) wasn't populating my address field as expected. After a bit of fidgeting and comparing with how address fields are formatted when I export my MailChimp list to a CSV file (in the app), it looks like the API call is **expecting five values**, each separated by two spaces.

So, to make the original code work, send an array like so:

```
$address = array('Line 1', 'Line 2', 'Line 3', 'Line 4', 'Line 5')
```

I imagine this five value syntax is to ensure it fills the Street Address, City, State, Zip, and Country fields, for the Address.

Comment: Thanks for this, still helpful to know :)